# The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/ uploads Wordpress on azure

Tags: wordpress, windows, azure-web-app-service

I have a wordpress site hosted on Windows azure.while I try to upload into media I am getting the following error “the uploaded file could not be moved to work-content/uploads/..”

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. You need to provide all the details and 
mention the issue clearly what exactly you want. Please refer the
[ask] link for more detail and update your question accordingly.

Comment: please provide the permission to uploads folder

Comment: The issue occurs due to folder permission level. Set permission to `755` for upload folder

Answer (score 0):

How do you deploy WordPress to Azure?

Whatever, there is an Azure Resource Manager template for the topic [`Create a WordPress site`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/201-aci-wordpress/), you can follow the work solution to do again and get a work web site of WordPress, which storage for files based on Azure Storage. I think it's a simple way to make it works, due to your question is not clear.

As reference for more details about deployment, you can refer to [`Deploying WordPress on Azure Web App for Containers`](https://markheath.net/post/wordpress-container-app-service).

Hope it helps, and expect your updated.

Comment: Created the wordpress app from the azure portal ...this issue has been occurring just few days back

Comment: @Nas123 The filesystem volume size of a Docker container is limited, so you need to use Azure Storage as the real store for `work-content/uploads/`, please refer to [`Create a WordPress site`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/201-aci-wordpress/).